# Single character string from java to plsql varchar2(1) causes 'character string buffer too small'

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, varchar

I have to call Oracle stored procedure from jdbc interface. Procedure takes a record type parameter which includes VARCHAR(2) field:

```
TYPE cust_account_rec_type IS RECORD (
    ... , status VARCHAR2(1), ... );
```

My jdbc query string declares record type variable and assigns value to status field, where right side is a query parameter. Then, calls procedure.

```
p_cust_account_rec.status   := :IN_insert_status;

someprocedure(p_cust_account_rec);
```

Java query call sets the value for *IN_insert_status* parameter:

```
callableStatement.setString("IN_insert_status", "I");
// callableStatement is type of java.sql.CallableStatement
```

after callableStatement.execute() i got

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Message points to line with this single character varchar variable. However, when i hardcode value in sql query string as:

```
  p_cust_account_rec.status   := 'I';
```

it works.

What is the problem with passing single character string in java, or what am I missing?

Comment: I am forbidden to make any database changes. It is external database and from that point of view, it is 'read only' for me.

Comment: take a look here, might be the same issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598969/character-string-buffer-too-small-error-in-oracle-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution. Actually, problem lies elsewhere.
I found that with oracle jdbc driver I am expected to set the query parameter values (in java) with the same order as they appeared in SQL, even thought I've used named parameters, not ? idexed.

So, I had query fragment like

```
p_cust_account_rec.account_name      := :IN_account_name;  -- VARCHAR2(240)
p_cust_account_rec.status            := :IN_insert_status; -- VARCHAR2(1)
```

and Java calls like (order important)

```
callableStatement.setString("IN_insert_status", "I");
callableStatement.setString("IN_account_name", "Some Account Name");
```

and it ended with IN_account_name = "I", and IN_insert_statis = "Some Account Name", which caused 'character buffer size error' due to insert_status VARCHAR2(1) nature.

I can't 100% confirm this for oracle jdbc cause I'm only reading decompiled code, but the problem was also mentioned http://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/07/23/oracle-jbdc-callablestatements-and-named-parameters/. However, it solved my problem.