# ORA-06502 Numerical OR Value Error CHARACTER STRING BUFFER TO SMALL

Tags: oracle

Oracle Function Giving Me Error while i execute this function . it will give an error like character buffer value is too small at line no 20

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fn_Lov_Purchase_Return (vComp_Id     NUMBER,
                                                   vLoc_Id      NUMBER,
                                                   vLIne_No     NUMBER,
                                                   vParam       NUMBER,
                                                   vAtt_Para    NUMBER,
                                                   vLot_No      VARCHAR2,
                                                   vDept_Id     NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   vPURC_NO   VARCHAR2 (20000);

   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT M.DOC_NO AS PURC_NO
        FROM RJN_GRN_TRANS_ITEMS I, RJN_GRN_TRANS_MASTER M
       WHERE     I.TRANS_ID = M.TRANS_ID
             AND M.TRANS_TYPE = 'GRN'
             AND M.COMP_ID = vComp_Id
             AND M.COMP_ID = vLoc_Id
             AND I.LINE_NO = vLIne_No
             AND I.PARAMETER_CODE = vParam
             AND I.ATT_PARAMETER_CODE = vAtt_Para
             --AND     I.LOT_NO= vLot_No
             AND M.DEPT_ID = VDept_Id;

   c1_Rec     c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   vPURC_NO := ' ';

   FOR c1_Rec IN c1
   LOOP
      IF (vPURC_NO) = ' '
      THEN
         vPURC_NO := c1_Rec.PURC_NO;
      ELSE
         vPURC_NO := vPURC_NO || ', ' || c1_rec.PURC_NO;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN (vPURC_NO);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      vPURC_NO := 'No-Records';
      RETURN vPURC_NO;
END;
/
```

Comment: How many rows are found, and how long are you expecting the aggregated result to be? (Too long for `listagg()` presumably.). Are you sure the error is from this function - line 20 doesn’t look right? What is the full error stack, and can you include the code that is calling it, particularly the definition of the variable that accepts the result?

Comment: If the problem is with the caller (seems so from comment on Littlefoot's answer), then [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17598969/266304).

Comment: i am calling this function from query. and input the perimeter from query also .

Comment: In which version of Oracle? Unless you've set 12cR2 up for it, if the result is more than 4000 bytes you can't use it from SQL anyway. Please edit your question to show what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If `vPURC_NO   VARCHAR2 (20000);` isn't large enough, either make it larger, or use a `CLOB` data type.

Comment: Could you edit your initial message and show us **how** you call that function from a query? Please, post the whole code you used, possibly copy/paste from your SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.